# How do I stop my image from overlapping my content?

Tags: css, wordpress

I have been requested to add a full-width banner image to some pages on a preexisting site that I am unfamiliar with editing. I was finally able to get the banner full-width using this CSS:

```
#BannerImage {
    position: absolute;
    left: 0;
    top: 0;
    height: 450px;
    width: 100%;
}
```

But now my content is flowing under the image.

Comment: it's because of `position: absolute;` making `#BannerImage` anchor to the dom, overlapping your other components

Answer (score 1):

Because you're using `position: absolute;` it's removing your banner image from the documents flow. This means it has no regard in position relative to the other elements on your page.

A simple fix would be by either changing your `position` property to either
`position: static;` or `position: relative`.

I hoped this helped.